# Best options for operation of rotary incremental encoders with micro controllers

Tags: microcontroller, encoder

At my workplace, I found a measuring device with six rotary encoders. The device is from the early 1990s. I wanted to reactivate the encoders, I even found software for it on floppy disks. However, to operate the device you need a so called DRC-Card, which reads the encoders (see picture 1). Exactly this card is now unfortunately not to be found anymore.

So I thought about the possibility to use a microcontroller instead of the DRC-Card to read the encoder signals and transfer them via USB to a PC. I would have to rewrite the software.

I should be able to write the software, but unfortunately I do not really know anything about electrical engineering.

**Therefore I turn to you with the request that you give me advice if you think this project is possible and how I can best start with this project?  Maybe you also have some advice on which micro controllers or other components are suitable for my project?**

Below, I will list some more information about the encoders I have found so far. (The manufacturer did not respond to my request and a data sheet is no longer available online. But I found the data sheet for an encoder, which is probably the [successor model](https://pdf.directindustry.com/pdf/gurley-precision-instruments/911s-rotary-incremental-encoder/14356-3140.html), see picture 2.)

```
Manufacturer: Gurley Precision Instruments
Model designation: 8211-1800-CCPA
Encoder Type: rotary incremental optical encoder, quadrature 2 channel
Max. number of Lines on Disc: 1,800
Max. pulses per revolution: 14,400
Max. frequency response with highest interpolation factor: 600 kHz
Input Power: +5 VDC
Encoder output: sin (phase A), cos (phase B), index
```

if possible all six encoders should be read simultaneously or with as little delay as possible. The rotary position of all encoders is used to compute a position and orientation.

Thank you very much, I am looking forward to any feedback from you.

---

Picture 1: Encoder connections to the (now unobtainable) DRC Card

[image: Picture 1: Encoder connections to the (now unobtainable) DRC Card]

---

Picture 2: Description of the successor model

[image: Picture 2: Description of the successor model]

---

Picture 3: Advertisement for the Encoder

[image: Picture 3: Advertisement for the Encoder]

---

Comment: Before you can choose a path, you'll need to know the rotation rate, number of lines, and desired accuracy.  These encoders seem to have an analog sine/cosine output such that suitable electronics can interpolate rather than simply count quadrature.  You also need to determine if it is necessary to read all six encoders with tightly coincident timing, or if they are to be used singly or if in groups but a few milliseconds of skew is acceptable.  Collectively these are reasons that questions asked on this site from an end user rather than design engineering perspective usually end up closed.

Comment: If you have none of the above information, hook one up to two ADC channels on an Arduino and experiment, perhaps you'll be able to discover what you need to know in order to select suitable electronics.

Comment: thanks for your important comment. i will add the information to my question above. It would be best if all six encoders were read out at the same time (or with as little delay as possible), because the rotary position of all encoders is included in a position/orientation calculation.

Comment: Most microcontrollers have multiple analog inputs, but only one ADC. You will need to read all six sequentially. But since you seem to need it for human input, such an ADC is fast enough to make it appear as simultaneously. Consider using a timer with a fixed cycle as trigger to start one sequence, for example once each 10 ms.

Comment: @NelsonOrange you will have to be more specific than 'at the same time', or we will have to suggest *very* expensive solutions. Is 1 ns skew acceptable? 1 us? 1ms?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. last week I connected the encoders to an arduino, to check if I get a signal. Unfortunately three of them don't work. Therefore I will not pursue this project any further. Thanks anyway, your comments have helped me a lot.